# How to execute INSERT INTO statement right after CREATE TABLE Mysql

Tags: mysql

I've written a program that creates a table and then runs a function that inserts records into that table.

Currently, when the program is run, it creates a table with a name based on the datetime.

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y_%m_%d'), '_new_table LIKE OLD_TABLE');
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Im running into an issue where Im uncertain how to insert into this newly created table.

How can I run the insert into this new table when I don't have the exact name of the table created?

```
INSERT INTO _new_table SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE id = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a variable for the table name.

Format the table name before you issue the CREATE TABLE statement. Store the table name in a variable.

```
SET @TABLE_NAME = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y_%m_%d'), '_new_table');
```

Use the variable in the CREATE TABLE statement.

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `', @TABLE_NAME, '` LIKE OLD_TABLE');
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Then use the same variable in the INSERT statement.

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `', @TABLE_NAME, '` SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE ID = ?');
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt USING @id;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to get the table name from `information_schema.tables`

```
 select * from information_schema.tables where date_format(create_time,'%Y-%m-%d') = current_date();
```

if you are creating one table for one day this might work.